# pythonで２次元配列の１つ目の要素から，２つ目の合計を算出

Tags: python, python3

２次元配列liがあり

```
li =[[1,2],
     [2,3],
     [3,4],
     [4,5],
     [1,3],
     [1,4]]
```

１つ目の要素が１である箇所の２つ目の要素の合計を計算したいです．
上のリストの場合，１つ目の要素が１である[1,2][1,3][1,4]の
２つ目の要素の合計を算出(2+3+4=9)といった具合です．

filter,map,sum,lambdaをうまく使えば，できると思うのですが・・・

分かりにくい文章で申し訳ありませんが，よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: いろいろな回答があるかと思われますので、これはその一つとして見てください。``sum([e[1] for e in li if e[0] == 1])`` このサンプルの流れは、リスト内の各要素について、0番目の要素が1のときに1番目要素を取得してリストとして出力（[2, 3, 4]）した後、これらを足し合わせています。

Comment: 早速の回答、ありがとうございます。
可能であれば、np.sum(li, axis=0)を用いる形で、表現できないかと考えています。
ナンセンスでしょうか。

Comment: いろいろな解がありますのでユーザの状況に合わせた方法で問題ないと思います。速度を気にされる場合は、それぞれで確認する必要があるかと思います。

Comment: @Tanaike さん、コメント欄で回答するのではなく、回答として投稿するようにして下さい。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 申し訳ありません。削除した方が好ましいようですと削除させていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

filter, mapを使っても可能ですが、あまりPythonicではありません。

```
filtered = filter(lambda e: e[0] == 1, li)
mapped = map(lambda e: e[1], filtered)
print(sum(mapped))
```

コメントで言われているように、(件数にもよりますが)内包表現を使ったほうが簡潔でオススメです。

```
print(sum(e[1] for e in li if e[0] == 1))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
内包表現のほうが、簡潔そうですね。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

numpy.whereを使ってみてはどうでしょう。

```
import numpy as np

li =[[1,2],
     [2,3],
     [3,4],
     [4,5],
     [1,3],
     [1,4]]

m = np.array(li)
idx = np.where(m[:,0]==1)
np.sum(m[idx, 1])
```

以下、追記。
お遊びレベルの修正ですが、pandasのDataFrameを使えば、次のようにまとめられます。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(li)
a = df.where(df[0]==1).sum()[1]
```

あと、ご質問のコメントの中にある回答ですが、

```
sum([e[1] for e in li if e[0] == 1])
```

は、内包表記の[]は省略できます。

```
sum(e[1] for e in li if e[0] == 1)
```

こちらは、中間のリストを作成しない分メモリ効率がよくなる場合があるようです（差が出るようなサイズで試したことがないので伝聞調です）。詳細な仕組みまでは説明しませんが、Pythonのジェネレータ式としてsumの中が機能しています。

Comment: whereの存在を知らなかったので、勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: pandasのDataFrameにも似たようなものがあるので追記しておきました。

Comment: それから、コメントに回答があったリスト内包表記ですが、ジェネレータ式に置き換えられます。見た目はリストの括弧`[ ]`をはずしただけです。